# Puppeteer not clicking button with text

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have a simple function that tries to accept the cookies 
Here's my code:

```
(async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://www.sport1.de/live/darts-sport');
        await page.click('button[text=AKZEPTIEREN]');
        // await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });

        // await browser.close();
    })();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookie popup is placed in an iframe. You have to switch to iframe by [contentFrame](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v10.4.0&show=api-elementhandlecontentframe) to be able to click on the accept button.

Also, if you want to filter by textContent, you need to use XPath. With CSS selector you can't get elements by its textContent.

```
const cookiePopUpIframeElement=await page.$("iframe[id='sp_message_iframe_373079']");
const cookiePopUpIframe=await cookiePopUpIframeElement.contentFrame();
const acceptElementToClick = await cookiePopUpIframe.$x("//button[text()='AKZEPTIEREN']");
await acceptElementToClick[0].click();
```

Comment: Thank you but in the last line you have to add [0].click();

Comment: Thanks, updated.